# Android Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral - Connection loss after bonding

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, bluetooth-peripheral

I am implementing Bluetooth Low Energy's HID over GATT (HOGP) profile on Android Lollipop. My target is to use the phone as a keyboard/mouse, which can just plug and play with the default BLE (HID) drivers in Windows 8.1 laptop. The Android phone is supposed to act as BLE peripheral and the laptop should be in BLE central role.

Currently, I am able to establish a very short connection with the laptop. But just right after I enter the passkeys, and bonded successfully with the laptop, the BLE connection will be lost. Have anyone faced this kind of problems before? Or have any solutions on it?

Also, I failed to add generic access service to the gatt server in Android. I am curious if GAP service is included in Android BLE communication by nature? The reason I want to include this service is for defining the "device name", "appearance", and the "peripheral connection parameter update" characteristics. How I can do so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get your system fixed,  I am seeing something kind of similar, where after bonding,  my device will go to paired list,  then about 20 sec later, the bluetooth on /off button  will automatically switch to off position, wait 10 sec,  then back
to on position, and my device is gone..